# Weird behavior upon splitting RDD into smaller RDDs and storing them in list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

because of resource constraints, I need to be able to split up a large RDD into n smaller RDDs and call `spark-submit` on them as separate jobs.
The code looks something like this:

```
def split_rdd_by_key(input_rdd, distinct_key_count, num_splits=10):


# Calc. chunk indexes - lower and upper bounds for each smaller rdd
chunk_gtor = __chunk_points(distinct_key_count, num_splits)

smaller_rdds = []
sort_key = "data_key"

# Create sets of smaller rdds by filtering on indexes 
for item in chunk_gtor:
    lbval, ubval = item[0], item[1]

    print "lbval=%s ubval=%s" % (lbval, ubval)
    filt_rdd = input_rdd.filter(lambda x : x.key.entity >= lbval \
                                and x.key.entity <= ubval)
    filt_count=filt_rdd.count()
    print "filt_count=%s" % filt_count
    smaller_rdds.append(filt_rdd)

return smaller_rdds
```

The code above prints the size of each smaller rdd as it is generated and appends it to the `smaller_rdds` list.

However, if I run the function above:

```
filtered_rdds=split_rdd_by_key(rdd, distinct_key_count)
```

and do the following:

```
# See the size of the 1st smaller rdd:
filtered_rdds[0].count()
```

it returns 31, which is MUCH smaller than what was printed when the function `split_rdd_by_key` was being run !!

Can anyone help explain this ? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I needed to make a call to `cache()` :

```
filt_rdd = dataflow_rdd.filter(lambda x : x.key.entity >= lbval \
                                  and x.key.entity <= ubval)
filt_rdd.cache()
```

Now it works ok :-)